# Create a new dataset based on the observations of the one and the column of the other

Tags: r

I am trying to solve an issue that I face...
lets say I have these two datasets, one drugs with their gene targets and the other patient data with the cancer genes:

```
docetaxel   carboplatin
AR      ACVR1C
CYP3A4  ALDH1A1
ESR1    ALDH3A1
NR3C1   ARFGEF1
TACR2   BAX
TDP1    NOTCH/MAST
TP53    BCL2L12
TUBA1A  BIRC2
TUBA1B  BRCA1
```

and

```
Patient ID  Breastcancergenes
1   ESR1-CCDC170
2   ESR1
3   BCL2L14-ETV6
4   ETV6-NTRK3
5   MYB-NFIB
6   NOTCH/MAST
7   ESR1
8   ESR1-CCDC170
9   BCL2L14-ETV6
10  MYB-NFIB
```

I would like to run a function in r that will create a new dataset (3rd one) that will learn from the observations of the patient data set and match with the drug of the other data set. for example like this below:

```
patient id breastcancergenes drug
2            ESR1            docetaxel
4            BAX             NA
6            NOTCH/MAST      carboplatin
```

I tried the left_join function but this didnt work for me so much. Has anyone any idea that could help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Should it be `4  ETV6-NTRK3 NA` in the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the first dataframe is called `df1`, then the second `df2` to get the third one you need to join them using `left_join` but before that, you need first to use `pivot_longer` to make df1 have drug-gene pairs at each row, instead of the current structure:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols=everything(),names_to = 'drug',values_to='gene')
```

Now, the two data frames can be joined:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% left_join(df1, by=c('Breastcancergenes'='gene'))
```

Comment: Looks like we came up with the same solution in parallel, so I've +1'd you for beating me to it!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming they need to be exact matches, then maybe this approach. `pivot_longer` on the first dataset creates a gene-drug reference. Then one can `left_join` patient and drug data by gene.

The question says "learn", but I assume it's a matching rather than a machine learning question?

```r
library(tidyverse)

drug_df <- tribble(
  ~docetaxel, ~carboplatin,
  "AR", "ACVR1C",
  "CYP3A4", "ALDH1A1",
  "ESR1", "ALDH3A1",
  "NR3C1", "ARFGEF1",
  "TACR2", "BAX",
  "TDP1", "NOTCH/MAST",
  "TP53", "BCL2L12",
  "TUBA1A", "BIRC2",
  "TUBA1B", "BRCA1"
) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "drug", values_to = "gene")

patient_df <- tribble(
  ~Patient_ID, ~Breastcancergenes,
  1, "ESR1-CCDC170",
  2, "ESR1",
  3, "BCL2L14-ETV6",
  4, "ETV6-NTRK3",
  5, "MYB-NFIB",
  6, "NOTCH/MAST",
  7, "ESR1",
  8, "ESR1-CCDC170",
  9, "BCL2L14-ETV6",
  10, "MYB-NFIB"
)

patient_df |> 
  left_join(drug_df, by = c("Breastcancergenes" = "gene"))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>    Patient_ID Breastcancergenes drug       
#>         <dbl> <chr>             <chr>      
#>  1          1 ESR1-CCDC170      <NA>       
#>  2          2 ESR1              docetaxel  
#>  3          3 BCL2L14-ETV6      <NA>       
#>  4          4 ETV6-NTRK3        <NA>       
#>  5          5 MYB-NFIB          <NA>       
#>  6          6 NOTCH/MAST        carboplatin
#>  7          7 ESR1              docetaxel  
#>  8          8 ESR1-CCDC170      <NA>       
#>  9          9 BCL2L14-ETV6      <NA>       
#> 10         10 MYB-NFIB          <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>